# Read ñ character on json file android

Tags: android, json

How to read the ñ character on my json file in android? i tried it using the alt+0241 but it only shows on my phone as a diamond shape with question mark on the middle.i will mark this answered for those who can. Thanks!

```
        for(int i=0;i<nameList.size();i++){


            if (nameList.get(i).equals(placetitle)){

                    PlaceImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.PlaceImage);

                    JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
                    String image_value = jo_inside.getString("image");
                    String resName = image_value.split("\\.")[2]; // remove the 'R.drawable.' prefix
                    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "drawable", getPackageName());
                    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(resId);
                    PlaceImage.setImageDrawable(image);
                    txtViewEx.setText(descriptionList.get(i)), true);
                    PlaceContact.setText(contactnoList.get(i));

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `&ntilde;` and then in your code:

Edit:

I'm not sure that txtViewEx object is but I guess this would be the correct call:

```
txtViewEx.setText(Html.fromHtml(descriptionList.get(i)), true);
```

Also if `contactnoList` can also contain **ñ** then you need:

```
PlaceContact.setText(Html.fromHtml(contactnoList.get(i)));
```

Comment: my code has error.. here : txtViewEx.setText(Html.fromHtml(parsedJsonString).descriptionList.get(i), true);

Comment: @user3875229 edit your question and add the original line. I'm not quite sure what you are doing here.

Comment: i have a library textjustify, if i dont include the ', true' it wont justify

Comment: @user3875229 oh, then add the true after. I updated accordingly.

Comment: heres the error when i include it:
The method setText(String, boolean) in the type TextViewEx is not applicable for the arguments (Spanned, boolean)

Comment: @user3875229 ahh guess you'll need to use a simple TextView.